# Select rows based on grouped rolling sum condition in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, cumulative-sum, rolling-computation

I have a table like the one below:

| ID | RID | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 5 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 | 6 |
| 7 | 2 | 3 |
| 8 | 2 | 2 |
| 9 | 2 | 4 |

I am trying to retrieve the rows of each `RID` until the rolling sum of `Count` is ≤ 10.

In this example I need all rows of `RID = 1` and only rows 1, 2 and 3 of `RID = 2`.

Expected answer:

| ID | RID | Count | Sum_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | NULL |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 | 5 | 9 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 | NULL |
| 6 | 2 | 6 | 7 |
| 7 | 2 | 3 | 10 |

I tried with `ROWNUM`, **inner query**, etc. but nothing worked out.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: FYI, when you say "only rows 1,2,3" that assumes there is some ordering taking taking place, which, unless you have an order by clause will not happen.  There here no default ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a cumulative sum of `Count` by `RID` and then select all rows where the cumulative count is less than or equal to 10.

Try this:

```sql
select
    *
from
    (
        select
            ID,
            RID,
            COUNT,
            sum(COUNT) over (partition by RID order by ID) as cum_count
        from
            my_table
    )
where
    cum_count <= 10
```

Comment: I had tried like it but it is giving me only the RID: 1 it is not giving me the RID: 2, I also like to get RID: 2 since the count of first three rows of RID:2 is <=10

Comment: Oh, you edited the question. I am editing my answer, so please let me know if it worked.

Comment: Thanks I had tried like it but it is giving me only the RID: 1 it is not giving me the RID: 2, I also like to get RID: 2 since the count of first three rows of RID:2 is <=10

Comment: I had done an order by ID it worked out Thanks